Simplifying Min with assumptions
Lots of ecological models use Liebig's law of the minimum when multiple essential resources may limit growth.  I want to break these equations into the special cases using Simplify with assumptions.  The following two examples work as expected:
Simplify[Min[R1, R2], R1 < R2]
(* R1 *)
Simplify[Min[a1 R1, a2 R2], a1 R1 < a2 R2]
(* a1 R1 *)

but this one doesn't:
Simplify[Min[a1 R1/q1, a2 R2/q2], a1 R1/q1 < a2 R2/q2]
(* Min[a1 R1/q1, a2 R2/q2] *)

How can I make Simplify recognize and apply this assumption?
I should add, this is happening behind-the-scenes in a package that works on user-defined functions and user-defined assumptions, so the simple solution of just replacing the Min function with the appropriate argument won't work.

It works with "Max". Therefore, I think it is a bug.

How about Simplify[   Min[a1  R1/q1, a2  R2/q2] /. {a1  R1/q1 -> t, a2  R2/q2 -> s},    a1  R1/q1 < a2  R2/q2 /. {a1  R1/q1 -> t, a2  R2/q2 -> s}] /. {s ->     a2  R2/q2, t -> a1  R1/q1} which results in (a1 R1)/q1?

@DanielHuber: This is a weakness, not a bug.

Simplify[Max[a1  R1/q1, a2  R2/q2], a1  R1/q1 > a2  R2/q2] also returns the input.

This behavior is inconsistent enough that I will report to Wolfram.
In the meanwhile, this answer by @Mr.Wizard put me on the path to solving this problem using TransformationFunctions with Condition's and Assuming.  Specifically:
tf[Min[a_, b_]] /; Simplify[a <= b] := a;
tf[Min[a_, b_]] /; Simplify[b < a] := b;
tf[Min[a_, b_]] /; Simplify[a > b] := b;
tf[Min[a_, b_]] /; Simplify[b >= a] := a;

Assuming[a1 R1/q1 < a2 R2/q2,
 Simplify[Min[a1 R1/q1, a2 R2/q2], TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, tf}]]
(* (a1 R1)/q1 *)

Assuming[a1 R1/q1 > a2 R2/q2, 
 Simplify[Min[a1 R1/q1, a2 R2/q2], TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, tf}]]
(* (a2 R2)/q2 *) 

Assuming[a2 R2/q2 > a1 R1/q1, 
 Simplify[Min[a1 R1/q1, a2 R2/q2], TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, tf}]]
(* (a1 R1)/q1 *)

Assuming[a2 R2/q2 < a1 R1/q1, 
 Simplify[Min[a1 R1/q1, a2 R2/q2], TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, tf}]]
(* (a2 R2)/q2 *)

All four versions of tf seem to be necessary.  This is my first time using TransformationFunctions, so I'd welcome any feedback on possible issues.

Interestingly, providing a slightly weaker assumption works
Simplify[Min[a1  R1/q1, a2  R2/q2], a1  R1/q1 <= a2  R2/q2]
(* (a1 R1)/q1 *)

Whereas
Simplify[Max[a1  R1/q1, a2  R2/q2], a1  R1/q1 <= a2  R2/q2]
(* Max[(a1 R1)/q1, (a2 R2)/q2] *)

but
Simplify[Max[a1  R1/q1, a2  R2/q2], a1  R1/q1 < a2  R2/q2]
(* (a2 R2)/q2 *)

If you want something that works for both Max and Min you can combine the conditions with &&.
